# Reset circuit of CP2102N and Atmega328P

Tags: reset, atmega328p, cp2102

I am working on a project where I want to programm the atmega via usb serial connection, just like an arduino.
In order to do that, I have wired up both chips as the documentation suggests. The reset circuit should be similar to the one, used by the arduino uno.

My problem appears when I am uploading a sketch, the reset pin on the arduino isn't trigged by the CP2102N. When reseting the Atmega manually in the right moment everything seems to work fine.
As I just have to give an logic LOW pulse(in the right moment) to the reset pin, I am using following circuit:
[image]

My guess is that the setting of the DTR Pin is wrong, which I configured in simplicity Studio.
[image]

Do you have any idea what is causing this problem?

Is it even correct to use a reset circuit, which was actually indented for another chip?

If more Information is needed please remind me kindly. Thank you for any feedback.

EDIT: The state of DTR pulses to HIGH just when I upload and falls down to LOW afterwards. What is needed at RESET is excaly the opposite: HIGH all the the time and should fall down to GND just when uploading. The state of RESET with given circuit is constantly HIGH right now.

Do you think a different value of the capacitor would solve that? Is a closed transistor a better and easier method for this application?

Comment: Does reset need to be held low throughout programming?

Comment: You should figure out if DTR never changes or if DTR changing does not cause reset to pulse low.  Typically the Arduino reset helper software drives both DTR and RTS as each has been used in some boards, but you could try switching to RTS and see if you get any different result.  Also make sure you actually got that QFN metalization soldered to the board - inspect at 10x magnification from an angle so you can see in there.

Comment: @Andyaka no, if reset were low the bootloader could not run.  It's pulsed low to get into the bootloader, and the programming commands then have to start before the bootloader times out.

Comment: I've had luck with a similar situation by changing that resistor to a 22 kOhm.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: @evildemonic Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this couldn't solve my problem, but thank you anyway for your suggestion :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for your reply and input. I have changed the question accordingly. I might NOT have the bottom properly soldered to GND, as I was afraid of a floating chip and thought that heat dissipation would not be needed.Or does the CP2102N need a very low impedance connection to GND? Because I do have other GND pins connected anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!SOLVED!
I changed the capacitor to a higher value (10µF). The upload does take longer now, as I have a longer reset procedure.(around one second more)